# How to get completely logout from FHSTwitterEngine in Twitter Rest API v1.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter

```
FHSTwitterEngine *engine = [FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine];
[engine clearAccessToken];
```

I tried above code but when I try to login again, textfields doesn't apear in `presentModalViewController`, it shows Authorize app button.

There is another method,  `[engine clearConsumer];` which results `Select and Copy the PIN` in `presentModalViewController`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe cookies still exists, that's the major issue with most of the twitter APIs on iOS.

This is how you can check for all cookies, put a check in between to clear only twitter cookies where you are performing a logout operation on twitter:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *each in cookieStorage.cookies) {
       // put a check here to clear cookie url which starts with twitter and then delete it
         [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Reno Jones

Comment: It worked !!! with below code inside for in

 if ([[each valueForKey:@"domain"] isEqualToString:@".twitter.com"]) {
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
}

Thanks buddy..

Answer (score 4):

Add below method in `FHSTwitterEngine.h` and `m` file.

```
- (void)logout
{
  NSLog(@"Logged out from twitter");

  //These is FHSTwitterEngine class method which clears accesstoken
  [self clearAccessToken]; 

  //clear cache of twitter from NSHTTPCookieStorage
  NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
  NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
  for (cookie in [storage cookies])
  {
    NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"twitter"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT** : Use these method like these :

```
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] logout];
```